# Multiple url locations in sitemap

Tags: web, configuration, sitemap

I have changed the url of some important pages within my website.

In order to maintain backward compatibility and to avoid breaking links which refer to those pages and already spreaded out, the original addresses are still alive.
So there are two addresses to exactly same pages.

How should it be defined in a sitemap?

```
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
   <url>
      <loc>http://www.example.com/old_address1</loc>
      <loc>http://www.example.com/new_address1</loc>
   </url>
   <url>
      <loc>http://www.example.com/old_address2</loc>
      <loc>http://www.example.com/new_address2</loc>
   </url>
</urlset>
```

Is this right?

Comment: This question should be on https://webmasters.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thanks. Now posting there.

Comment: Cross posted: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/111641/when-changing-page-urls-how-do-i-include-both-old-and-new-urls-together-in-the

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To summarise your problem, you have created a new endpoint where you are serving the user.  But you don't want a user with the old URL to land on an isolated page.  To solve this problem, you hosted both URLs on the server.  But now, how do you tell the GoogleBot that both are same page?

Per what you have tried thus far, I assume you would prefer a solution using the sitemap file.

```xml
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <url>
        <loc>http://www.example.com/new_address1</loc>
        <xhtml:link rel="canonical" href="http://www.example.com/old_address1" />
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>http://www.example.com/new_address2</loc>
        <xhtml:link rel="canonical" href="http://www.example.com/old_address2" />
    </url>
</urlset>
```

There are other ways you can accomplish this.  One way is to specify the old one as a canonical URL using `rel="canonical"` in link tag in `HEAD` section of the page itself.

```html
<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.example.com/old_address2" />
```

For reference, please check these links:

1. [Consolidate duplicate URLs](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066)
2. [Separate-urls](https://developers.google.com/search/mobile-sites/mobile-seo/separate-urls)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [googleblog](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2006/10/multiple-sitemaps-in-same-directory.html)

Multiple sitemaps might be what you want.They should be in the same directory and might be named thus:

```
http://www.example.com/old_sitemap.xml
http://www.example.com/new_sitemap.xml
```

Each containing their own urls.

Old:

```
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
   <url>
      <loc>http://www.example.com/old_address1</loc>
   </url>
   <url>
      <loc>http://www.example.com/old_address2</loc>
   </url>
</urlset>
```

New:

```
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
   <url>
      <loc>http://www.example.com/new_address1</loc>
   </url>
   <url>
      <loc>http://www.example.com/new_address2</loc>
   </url>
</urlset>
```

Comment: I meant: how to tell the crawler that these URLs are canonical. In your way i can put them also in the same file...

Comment: Canonical signals can't come from the XML sitemap. You'll need to implement that signal in either the HTML head or the HTTP header. "All pages listed in a sitemap are suggested as canonicals", as per Google's canonical support site.

Answer (score 0):

XML sitemaps are only valid with one  tag per URL, however you can list both the old and the new within the same XML sitemap if needed. For example:

```
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
   <url>
      <loc>http://www.example.com/old_address1</loc>
   </url>
   <url>
      <loc>http://www.example.com/old_address2</loc>
   </url>
</urlset>
```

With that said, however you might want to consider other setups depending on your intent for both the old and the new URLs. If both users and search engines no longer need to see the pages implementing a 301 redirect would likely make the most sense.

Otherwise, if users still need to find the site but the site doesn't need to be indexed implementing a [canonical](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066) will consolidate links without a redirect.

With either option, you should only include URLs that you want search engines to index. If the old content is no longer valid and should not be found in search consider dropping those URLs from the XML sitemap altogether and depend on the canonicals to pass over the link equity.

Additional information [here](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/183668?hl=en).